# Q: Office Script - Erase data from Column

Tags: typescript, office-scripts

could you guys lend me a hand

I need to convert some VBA code to Office Script and I'm Strugling, i need to erase data from a column with certain parameters

here is the code:

```
Sub processing()

    On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    ' concatenate Macro
    Dim var As String
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim column As Integer
    Dim concatened As String
    Dim hours() As String
    Dim cursor As Integer
    Dim person As Integer
    Dim sum As Double
    
    ' erasing columns

    For column = Sheets("Parameters").Cells(2, 4) To Sheets("Parameters").Cells(2, 5)
        For row = Sheets("Parameters").Cells(2, 2) To Sheets("Parameters").Cells(2, 3)
            
            Sheets("Projects").Cells(row, column) = ""
            
        Next row
        
        Sheets("Projects").Cells(3, column) = ""
        
    Next column
```

If someone could give me a light where to start, I'd be glad.

Comment: can you post the entire code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear the data in any range using [(Range).clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.range?view=office-scripts&WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-4029057#clear_applyTo_) method.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook)
{
  const paramSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Parameters");
  const param: number[] = [
    +paramSheet.getCell(0, 0).getValue(),
    +paramSheet.getCell(0, 1).getValue(),
    +paramSheet.getCell(1, 0).getValue(),
    +paramSheet.getCell(1, 1).getValue()
  ];
  const targetSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  const targetRange = targetSheet.getRangeByIndexes(param[0], param[1], param[2], param[3]);
  targetRange.clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents);
}
```

I recommend you referring to the [Basic Samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/excel-samples?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-4029057).